# how to decide if StreamingResponse was closed in FastAPI/Starlette?

Tags: python, fastapi, starlette, asgi

When looping a generator in StreamingResponse() using FastAPI/starlette

https://www.starlette.io/responses/#streamingresponse

how can we tell if the connection was somehow disconnected, so a event could be fired and handled somewhere else?

Scenario: writing an API with [`text/event-stream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource), need to know when client closed the connection.

Comment: May be you can override [`listen_for_disconnect`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/93494a46ee0f2e8b1eeafd12e466ebac15037b41/starlette/responses.py#L230-L234)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `request.is_disconnected()`. From Starlette's [docs](https://www.starlette.io/requests/#body):

> In some cases such as long-polling, or streaming responses you might need to determine if the client has dropped the connection. You can determine this state with disconnected = await request.is_disconnected().

Unfortunately, there seems to be no other documentation regarding this API. Have a look at the MR that introduced this feature: https://github.com/encode/starlette/pull/320